# LoadHTML & SaveHTML loops unintentionally

Tags: replace, hyperlink, setattribute

I created a function that counts all the hyperlinks on the current page, and changes the hyperlink to https://www.google.com . however, there is only 1 hyperlink on my page the code keeps looping 29 times and i cant find why.

```
function linkreplacer() {
$currenturl = file_get_contents((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"); //this is a wordpress function, i am positive that this works
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->loadHTML($currenturl);
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("a");
echo "The linkreplacer has found ".count($elements)." hyperlinks on this page </br>";
foreach($elements as $el) {
    $el->setAttribute('href', "https://www.google.com");
}
printf( '%s', $doc->saveHTML() );
}
```

Comment: Try to save the html in local file and actually see the html yourself., the one which is returned by your function. It might be possible that you actually are getting that many links.

Comment: Will this not create an infinite loop since you are trying to request your own page which then requests itself again and this goes on and on?

Comment: May be it is that you are accessing same page 29 times before a timeout reaches.